# C Program struct error assigning type struct node from int

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, incompatibility

I'm new here so sorry for not providing all information I should to get help I need but here goes.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* previous;
};

*currentB = MultByTen(*currentB); // this is a line in another function.
                                  // currentB is a struct node with data it in.

struct node* MultByTen(struct node* current) {
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    newNode->data = 0;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    newNode->previous = current;
    current->next = newNode;
    return current;
}
```

I'm getting  "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct node’ from type ‘int’" from that one line of code I have comments next to.
 I'm returning a struct node* so i don't know why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

-EDIT:
currentB is a linked list with data it in. it is

```
struct node* currentB = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

For the purposes of an example it is 1->2->3->4->NULL and what I want MultByTen is just to add a 0 to the end of the list so it'll become 1->2->3->4->0->NULL

Comment: What is the definition of `currentB`?  What is the definition of `MultByTen`?

Comment: Please use an [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) for your code for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `currentB` is declared as `struct node *currentB`? You try to assign a pointer to a structure, to an actual instance of the structure (`*currentB` is not a pointer but the actual instance). The call is also wrong in this case.

The line should be:

```
currentB = MultByTen(currentB);
```

Note the missing `*`.

May I suggest that you try to find a tutorial on pointers and how they are handled?